# Postgres/AWS Redshift: Pivot data to column long form

Tags: sql, join, subquery, amazon-redshift

I currently have some data of the form below.

```
userid |      event_time      | event_duration (secs) | first_activity | last_activity
   A      2017-01-01 02:20:34             16               E1                 E2     
   A      2017-03-01 11:23:43             12               E2                 E6
   B      2017-01-01 08:24:32             53               E1                 E4
   C      2017-01-01 23:19:21             43               E3                 E11
```

I would like to get it into the form:

```
userid |      event_time      | activity
   A      2017-01-01 02:20:34      E1
   A      2017-01-01 02:20:50      E2     
   A      2017-03-01 11:23:43      E2                
   A      2017-03-01 11:23:55      E6
   B      2017-01-01 08:24:32      E1                
   B      2017-01-01 08:25:25      E4
   C      2017-01-01 23:19:21      E3                
   C      2017-01-01 23:20:04      E11
```

I can do this quite easily by:

```
SELECT userid, event_time, first_activity
FROM table
UNION
SELECT userid, event_time + event_duration * interval '1 seconds', last_activity
FROM table
```

However, I'd like a way to avoid duplicating the query twice using `UNION`s. Is there a neat way to create the form I require without `UNION`ing two queries?

Comment: Do not tag questions with Postgres if you use Redshift. [From the Redshift manual](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html): "*Do not assume that the semantics of elements that Amazon Redshift and PostgreSQL have in common are identical*"

Answer (score 2):

The question was only tagged with Postgres when this answer was written.

You can use a lateral join:

```
select v.*
from t, lateral
     (values (t.userid, t.eventtime, t.first_activity),
             (t.userid, t.eventtime + t.event_duration * interval '1 second', t.last_activity)
     ) v(userid, eventtime, activity);
```

As an editorial note.  You can write this without the comma:

```
select v.*
from t cross join lateral
     (values (t.userid, t.eventtime, t.first_activity),
             (t.userid, t.eventtime + t.event_duration * interval '1 second', t.last_activity)
     ) v(userid, eventtime, activity);
```

The `, lateral` is the one case where I actually prefer the comma in the `FROM` clause.  It is interesting to note that SQL Server uses the `APPLY` keyword for lateral joins.  Oracle supports both `LATERAL` and `APPLY`.

Comment: Oracle supports lateral since 12.1: https://www.slideshare.net/MarkusWinand/modern-sql/11

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Unfortunately using `, lateral` gives the following error on `v(userid, eventime, activity)`: `function values(character varying, timestamp without time zone, character varying) does not exist`

Comment: @Black . . . What version of Postgres are you using?  I believe lateral was introduced in 9.3.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I'm using Redshift which is based on an 8.0 version.